# Is there a way to sort PHP array_merge based on raw[2]?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, merge

I am creating a time attendance PHP script. I started from storing data in the database MySQL and use different tables for the Punch-in/Punch-out, Breaks, Lunch/Dinner breaks. 
Each one of the casualties mentioned before have a table which is structured with an:
`ID, start, end, flag`

I have already tried to do this with the following code of `foreach` but unsuccessfully!

```
foreach ($total as $key => $row) {
   $start[$key]  = $row['start'];
}
$final = array_multisort($start, SORT_DESC,  $total);
echo $final;
```

Here is the code that I have made with 2 SELECT MySQL queries

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM time WHERE username = 
'$user_check' ORDER BY start DESC");
$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$data[] = $row;
} $db->next_result();
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM break WHERE username = 
'$user_check' ORDER BY start DESC");
$data2 = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$data2[] = $row;
}
$total = array_merge ($data, $data2);
```

I would like to have 1 array of this 2 queries sorted `DESC` by `start` as I will use this array to populate a table in `DESC` order.

Comment: Why not use `UNION ALL`? `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM time WHERE username = '$user_check'  UNION ALL SELECT * FROM break WHERE username = '$user_check') ORDER BY start DESC`.

Comment: I think Felippe is totally right, if the tables has the same structure, let do the DB all the work, fallco

Comment: This is funny i though a lot how to make this work, without thinking of UNION. Thank you guys

Comment: As long as you can tell a break from a clock in record it is easier to have them altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` in your query, instead of merge arrays. Let the database do the work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM time WHERE username = '$user_check'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT * FROM break WHERE username = '$user_check'
) ORDER BY start DESC
```

PS: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. You should use prepared statement instead.